# Difference between backup-SPFarm and Backup-SPConfigurationDatabase in sharepoint foundation 2010

Tags: powershell, sharepoint-foundation, backup

I want to know difference between `backup-SPFarm` and `Backup-SPConfigurationDatabase` powershell command.

I know backup-SPFarm is used to take backup of whole farm then why to use Backup-SPConfigurationDatabase to take configuration backup.  Does backup-SPFarm command not take a configuration backup?

Comment: But all the documentation says that no SP 2010 restore tools will restore the configurationDB or the Central Admin contentDB, so why back it up? And, in terms of disaster recovery, if you need SharePoint installed to run a restore and the configDB has to be SQL Server restored, what is the point of a farm backup or any config only backup?

Answer (score 1):

There is actually some functional overlap between the two cmdlets, and both can be used to create a configuration-only backup of a SharePoint 2010 farm. When it comes to generating configuration-only backups, though, each of the two cmdlets are suited for different use-cases.

I put together a blog post some time ago that answers exactly the question you posed. Check it out for more information:

http://sharepointinterface.com/2010/10/03/a-tale-of-two-cmdlets/

I hope that helps!

Answer (score 0):

Basically, backup-SPFarm backsup the entire SharePoint Farm while backup-SPConfigurationDatabase backsup only the configuration database associated with that particular Sharepoint Farm.

Comment: Is backup taken by backup-SPFarm is sufficient to restore entire farm or we also need backup taken by backup-SPConfigurationDatabase command ?

Comment: Nope. 
Farm backup will also backup configuration db for you.